# Select giving different results with different date formats

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I'm building a query on SQL Server, and I have the following line:

```
SELECT ISNULL(CONVERT(INT, SUM(fi.qtt)), 0)
FROM   fi,
       st
WHERE  st.ref = fi.ref
       AND rdata LIKE '%2021%'
```

which works like a charm. Only thing going wrong is that instead of definig the year (2021) I want it to get last year results. So I got to this point:

```
SELECT ISNULL(CONVERT(INT, SUM(fi.qtt)), 0)
FROM   fi,
       st
WHERE  st.ref = fi.ref
       AND rdata LIKE '%DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())%'
```

which gives me result 0 (zero).

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Dates are binary values, they have no format. What is `rdata`? If it's a `date` you only need to write a range comparison between the start and end of the year. If not - that's multiple serious bugs. First, there's no guarantee the field will contain valid date strings and even if it does, what they mean. Second, `LIKE '%..%'` can't use indexes which means your query will have to scan the entire table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in your question is because you need to concatenate the result of `DATEADD()` to the string used in the `LIKE` operation:

```
SELECT ISNULL(CONVERT(INT, SUM(fi.qtt)), 0)
FROM   fi,
       st
WHERE  st.ref = fi.ref
       AND rdata LIKE '%' + DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE()) + '%'
```

However you should note that the far better approach is to use the `YEAR()` function instead:

```
SELECT ISNULL(CONVERT(INT, SUM(fi.qtt)), 0)
FROM   fi,
       st
WHERE  st.ref = fi.ref
       AND YEAR(rdata) = YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1
```

Comment: @HoneyBadger was in the middle of an edit to include that :)

Comment: `YEAR(rdata) =whatever` isn't SARGable. It's better to use a range comparison with a date generates using `DATEFROMPARTS`

Comment: This doesn't make sense either, in my opinion. How can a date (and time) value be `LIKE` anything; `LIKE` is for strings, like a `varchar`. The clause `YEAR(rdata) = YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1` is also not SARGable, so won't be performant; use date boundaries.

Comment: You're more than welcome to add your own answer. To be honest I only answered this as the OP mistakenly tagged jQuery and felt it was an easy solution, although it appears not.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `LIKE 'SomeCodeHere'` because `LIKE` does not execute anything, it just expects a string pattern.

For dates, it's best to use date ranges. This means you will be able to utilize indexes properly.

> You should also use explicit join syntax, rather than the old comma-join syntax which was deprecated many decades ago.

```sql
SELECT ISNULL(CONVERT(INT, SUM(fi.qtt)), 0)
FROM  fi
JOIN  st ON st.ref = fi.ref
WHERE rdata >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1, 1, 1)
  AND rdata <  DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE())    , 1, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ISNULL(CONVERT(INT, SUM(fi.qtt)), 0)
FROM   fi,
       st
WHERE  st.ref = fi.ref
       AND rdata LIKE '%'+Convert(varchar(25),Year(DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())))+'%'
```

By looking into your query i think that rdata contains varchar data with date parts.
This query should work.